Movie or TV show set in the 1900s with two storylines
My mom recently saw a movie or TV show and we cannot figure out the title. It is probably in English language (British maybe) and produced within the last 10 years.
Here's what she remembers:
The movie/show started out with at least two (possibly intertwining) storylines and is set sometime in the early or mid 1900s.
The first storyline is about a wife whose very devoted husband travels a lot and she is cheating on him with a guy who owns or works at a tea shop. He is drugging her with something that ultimately makes her addicted. In order to supply her with more drugs he introduces her to another guy who takes nude pictures of her (maybe used for blackmail later, but I cannot be sure).
The second storyline is about a girl who wants to work in a fashion store against her parents' will, so she leaves her hometown to work in the city at said store. She has a (female) boss who she starts out running errands for. One of those errands is buying tea at the tea shop of the guy from storyline number one. The guy tells her that he can help out with her apartment situation (apparently she doesn't have a decent place to live or something) and puts her in the same building as the photographer from storyline number one.
I'm not sure if this is a 100% accurate and unfortunately my mom doesn't remember more and hasn't watched the movie/show till the end, so this is all I've got.
Suggestions highly appreciated.
